# Unit testing IO Int and similar in Haskell

Tags: haskell

From [Ninety-Nine Haskell Problems](https://wiki.haskell.org/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems):

[Question 23](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/21_to_28): *Extract a given number of randomly selected elements from a list.*

This is a partial solution. For simplicity, this code just selects one element from a list.

```
import System.Random (randomRIO)

randItem :: [a] -> IO a
randItem xs = do
    i <- randomRIO (0,length xs - 1)
    return $ xs !! i
```

so `randItem [1..10]` would return an `IO Int` that corresponds to (but does not equal) some Int from 1 through 10.

So far, so good. But what kind of tests can I write for my randItem function? What relationship--if any--can I confirm between the input and output?

I can use the same logic as the above function to produce `m Bool`, but I cannot figure out how to test for `m Bool`. Thank you.

Comment: I think you want to define `randItem' :: SomeClass m => [a] -> m a`, where `SomeClass` provides a function to use in place of `randomRIO`. Then, if you define an appropriate instance of `SomeClass` for `IO`, you can use `randItem' [1..10] :: IO` to get a random value, or `randItem' [1..10] :: SomeTestMonad` which provides an alternate, deterministic implementation of the `randomRIO` replacement for testing.

Comment: `randItem :: [a] -> IO a` would then just be a specialization of `randItem'` to the `IO` type.

Comment: @chepner Why define a new type class? What's wrong with `RandomGen`?

Comment: @MarkSeemann Probably nothing; my Haskell skills aren't up actually implementing my suggestion, at least not quickly. (I tried using `RandomGen`, but couldn't put the pieces together correctly, so just posted the vague suggestion instead of an actual answer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a couple of things you can do. If you're using QuickCheck, you could write the following properties:

- The length of the returned list should be equal to the input length.
- All elements in the returned list should be elements of the list of candidates.

Apart from that, the beauty of Haskell's Random library is that (as most other Haskell code) it's deterministic. If, instead of basing your implementation on `randomRIO`, you could base it on `randomR` or `randomRs`. This would enable you to pass some known `RandomGen` values to some deterministic unit test cases (not QuickCheck). These could serve as regression tests.

---

I've now published [an article about the above approach](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/07/09/typing-and-testing-problem-23), complete with [source code](https://github.com/ploeh/HasProblem23).

Comment: I'm missing something with QuickCheck. Still can't see how to accomplish elem (IO Int) [Int]. Here's what I tried quickCheck ((\list -> elem (randItem list) list) :: [Int] -> Bool) Very new to Haskell. I'll implement your second suggestion (randomR). Thank you.

Comment: @Shay Try to write a function with the type `RandomGen g => g -> Int -> [a] -> [a]`. I'm away from my development environment for the next many hours, so that suggestion may contain a typo or two (I'm writing this on my phone), but hopefully it should give you an idea on how to proceed.

Comment: "All elements in the returned list should be elements of the list of candidates." -- I think this it is a consequence of the free theorem. If so, no need to test for that! :-)