# Using QuickCheck for testing if a list is shuffled

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I need to use QuickCheck to check if a list of integers is truly shuffled

```
prop_fastShuffle_correct :: [Int] -> Property
prop_fastShuffle_correct s = ???
```

My shuffle function has this signature:

```
fastShuffle :: [a] -> IO [a]
```

No need to go for full correctness of every potential property of your shuffle, e.g., that it’s pseudorandom.

Can someone point me into the right direction? I'm not too familiar with QuickCheck.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46791466/126014 for a similar type of problem.

Comment: What is being truly shuffled?

Comment: Realistically, you can only check that it's a permutation of the input, which can be implemented using something like `sort output == sort input`.

Comment: A shuffle function can sometimes return the function exactly in the same order as it was.