# QuickCheck property with type [Int] -> Property

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm very new to QuickCheck. I know how to write QuickCheck properties like :

```
prop_rev_involutive l = (reverse $ reverse l) == l
```

that test the reverse  function.

But now I need to write a QuickCheck  property with this signature

```
prop_fastShuffle_correct :: [Int] -> Property
prop_fastShuffle_correct s = undefined
```

That suppose to test a fastShuffle function I wrote with this signature :

```
fastShuffle :: [a] -> IO [a]
```

I know exactly what I want to test but not sure how the signature

```
 [Int] -> Property
```

should impact my code. I assume that my `prop_fastShuffle_correct` function gets a randomly generated array of integers but I don't understand what it means to return a value from type  Property and how to do it.

Hope that someone can give me some guide.

Thanks!

Comment: It'll be easier if you write your System Under Test (SUT) as a pure function. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46791854/126014 for some hints for doing that and using QuickCheck for property-based testing with randomness.

Comment: If you truly *must* test a function that returns `IO a`, you can use `ioProperty` or `idempotentIOProperty`.

Comment: I'm trying to use   monadicIO to test my function that returns IO and I think it is working!